# Docker Compose Network Multicast

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to connect different wildflys with each other over multicast. If I run the wildflys locally on my machine, they talk to each other over the 226.0.1.1

but in docker compose there is no communication in the network.

my current compose file looks like this:

```
version: '3.5'
services:

  wildfly1:
    build: ./wildfly_image
    image: wildfly:latest
    environment:
    - WILDFLYNAME=wildfly1
    networks:
      wildfly_network:

  wildfly2:
    build: ./wildfly_image
    image: wildfly:latest
    environment:
    - WILDFLYNAME=wildfly2
    networks:
      wildfly_network:

networks: 
  wildfly_network:
    ipam:
      driver: default
```

if I run `docker network inspect <wildfly_network>` I get the following result:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "wildfly_network",
        "Id": "fb6971c11fc46c9489ea09a32da8d775818aa60fe4a9ce70ef6622455b9d9f26",
        "Created": "2019-04-11T12:23:12.177429621Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.18.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.18.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": true,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "31edc263ca9e6114dac70cc1347093159eb64028730459ae316ffe941dae9c57": {
                "Name": "wildfly2_1",
                "EndpointID": "f26daa7b38bcaf40db337e29c3fe501a48b415d14def30b3ed943d9d309cbbf8",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:04",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.4/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "32e30b11d07e1c30b9a885493e8614d0e809f537f99c46c6386492aa4a0a010a": {
                "Name": "wildfly1_1",
                "EndpointID": "7e79bcfacd28eb5a90734f21063655430e4a795391dbd4859b21d337b23c684a",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:05",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.5/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.network": "wildfly_network",
            "com.docker.compose.project": "docker",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "1.23.2"
        }
    }
]
```

did someone see my issue?

**thanks**

Comment: You really should not use multicast addressing in the RESERVED range.To make up your own multicast addresses, we have the Organization-Local Scope (`239.0.0.0/8`), and you should use an address in that range.

Comment: I ran some simple multicast tests between a couple of docker containers on the same network, and everything seems to work out fine. It would help if you could provide sufficient information in your question to reproduce the behavior you're seeing.

Comment: I created a GitHub repo for this: https://github.com/auryn31/wildfly-docker-multicast-test . I hope I get it right :-D thanks a lot

Comment: the wildflies seems to talk over multicast, but only to themself?!

Comment: normal multicast seems to work. I tested a commandlinetool and wrote a simple java program, they both can communicate between containers over multicast. But wildfly won't work

Comment: I found the issue and answered the question for myself :-D thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue with the following command:

```
ENTRYPOINT /opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh -b=0.0.0.0 -bmanagement=0.0.0.0 -Djboss.server.default.config=standalone-full-ha.xml -Djboss.node.name=${WILDFLY_NAME} -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djgroups.bind_addr=$(hostname -i) -Djboss.messaging.cluster.password=${CLUSTER_PW}
```

You have to bind the jgroup address to the local address of the container, change the cluster pw and use ipv4

i also updated the GitHub repo to show the current running cluster

https://github.com/auryn31/wildfly-docker-multicast-test

Answer (score -2):

In case the only purpose of network to make your services accessible, try directly accessing services within docker compose directly e.g.http://wildfly1 , http://wildfly2. Docker compose should add both services in default network and made available with service name to other services in compose. for more info refer [docker doc](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/)

```
version: '3.5'
services:

  wildfly1:
    build: ./wildfly_image
    image: wildfly:latest
    environment:
    - WILDFLYNAME=wildfly1

  wildfly2:
    build: ./wildfly_image
    image: wildfly:latest
    environment:
    - WILDFLYNAME=wildfly2
```